# Why Is the cloth simulation on my model turning into spikes?

Tags: physics

I'm not entirely sure how to describe this, but the cloth physics on my model seem to be going everywhere.

My goal is to get the clothing to rest on the model. The character model is 1.6 meters tall. Let me know if there's any other information you need!

[image: Cloth Physics]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/cloth/settings/collisions.html Try reducing the distance to 0.001 ish on all the colliders. The shirt is being pulled up by the body collision, not sure why the breasts are poking thru. It looks likes the pants are exploding because of internal collisions. Also, you might want to put the waist band into the pinning group.

Comment: In addition to what @RonJensen says, such spikes may also be the result of a solidify modifier if the normals are incosistent, especially if you enable even thickness and high quality normals in the modifier. Incosistent normals may very well be the result of self intersections, which in turn may be the result of the soft body solver settings needing to be tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully tell but...did you bake the cloth physics, and then edit your mesh? If you edit the mesh after a bake, a lot of the times it will end up like this, especially if you edit pinned vertices. Remove the physics, make your edits, and then reapply the cloth physics.