# Threads breaking while stitching a tshirt using cloth simulation

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I have been trying to stitch a basic t-shirt using two separate meshes (back and front patterns).

[image: Front pattern]

[image: Back pattern]

I tried converting these curves into meshes and then filled them.

After that I extruded one of the meshes and joined it to the other to form the 'threads'.

[image: Before stitching]

Upon running the cloth simulation the model is giving weird results where the threads are breaking instead of being sewed even though the sewing feature was on.

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I correct it?

Comment: How have you filled the front and back outlines? It looks like they are ngons. This does not work because it lacks the geometry to bend.

Comment: I also think ngons in the front and back outlines are causing this problem, but I have filled the outlines and do not know how to remove the ngons.

Comment: I would start with a plane and subdivide it a few times (but keep it as low-poly as you can). Then edit this quad mesh and remove faces that you don't need to get the shape you want. Here's an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/247587/107598